# Reuse ES6 fetch object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, fetch

I'm using webpack to bundle my JS so I can use it on the server and client. One thing that I'm finding difficult is using a fetch object in both places. On the server side, there's node fetch

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

and on the client-side I don't have to import anything and the `window.fetch` object should be used.

Is there a way to conditionally import the fetch object so it's used server side with `node-fetch`, and used client side with `window.fetch`?

I've tried this:

```
if(window == null) {
  import fetch from 'node-fetch';
}
```

but imports have to be 'top level'

I also tried mutating the fetch object if window is present:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

if(window) fetch = window.fetch;
```

but fetch becomes read-only.

Is there a work around? Currently I have 2 files one with the import and one without (for server/client respectively) but I want to avoid duplicate code.

Comment: You do not want to bundle your client js libs and your server js libs together because the client js libs are visible to clients.

Comment: You could [replace the `import` statement when you're bundling it](https://www.npmjs.com/package/webpack-replace) with something like `var fetch = window.fetch`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
var fetch = window?window.fetch:require('node-fetch').fetch;
```

**Edited**

If you are on strict mode, like [Mike](https://stackoverflow.com/users/371184/mike-c) commented below:

```
var fetch = typeof window === 'object' && 
    window?window.fetch:require('node-fetch').fetch;
```

Comment: Not if they're running in strict mode. It will cause a ReferenceError when attempting to access `window` like that.

Answer (score 2):

You could create a module that conditionally returns the correct fetch, rather than importing `node-fetch` directly:

```
/* fetch.js */
// default to native fetch, if available
let activeFetch = fetch;

if (!activeFetch) {
    activeFetch = require('node-fetch');
}

export default activeFetch;
```

Then you could import your wrapper and it should contain the correct version for each environment:

```
import fetch from './fetch';
// should be node-fetch for server, window.fetch for client-side
```